# Duplicating part of graph in neo4j/cypher

Tags: version-control, graph, duplicates, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph such as

```
A-->B-->C-->D
    |-->E-->F
        |-->G
        |-->H
```

How can I duplicate it from B, keeping properties and relationships(include relationship types), and append it to A, so it would look like

```
A-->B-->C-->D
|   |-->E-->F
|       |-->G
|       |-->H
|
|-->B2-->C2-->D2
    |--->E2-->F2
         |--->G2
         |--->H2
```

The purpose is to provide a "staging" version of the entity (A), that can be edited without affecting the one being shown - B and B2 has a version property by which they can be ordered. The changes made to B must be saved continuously while one is working on it, and until the changes are either cancelled or commited. After a commit is made on the staging version, the new one (B2) will be given B.version+1 as version.

**edit:** The 3rd and 4th columns in the example are not fixed, B can have any amount of nodes connected to it, and so can those.

Comment: Is the structure of your graph fixed or could there be an `I` node? If so, do you want a consistent numbering for all nodes, e.g. the next one being B3 through I3?

Comment: There could be any amount of nodes in the 3rd and 4th columns, so yes there could be an I node.
The numbering was only for the example, to show that for example B2 is the clone of B. The version is kept in B.version, B2.version, nothing is needed to be changed in the duplication

Comment: So you're never going to commit just a part of the graph? And how about new nodes and relationships from one version to another?

Comment: Yes, the whole thing gets duplicated at once, that's why I would want cypher to do it. At the point when this duplication would happen the two versions are equal. (I am not sure if I understood correctly your 2nd question.)

Comment: I was wondering if the amount of nodes in the 3rd and 4th column can change from one version to the next.